# Change parameter pointer address

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I need some help with realloc().

Imagine i have a pointer, and i have to realloc this pointer for some reason, how would i give this pointer back to the guy who called my function?

Exmaple:

```
char* fancy = malloc(sizeof(char))
fancyFunction(char* fancy)
{
    fancy = realloc(200 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Lets suppose realloc() has to move all the garbage in my pointer 'fancy' to a new address.
How could i return this new address, without using 'return'?

Is there a way to pass the address of the pointer itself to the address?
Like:

```
fancyFunction(&fancy)
```

whereas 'fancy' itself is the pointer mentioned above.
How would i then proceed?

Comment: What's wrong with `return fancy;` ?

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is *always* 1, by definition. There’s no need to put it into the code, it’s clutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by exactly what you said:

```
fancyFunction(&fancy)
```

(add `;` to make this a complete statement)

The callee will be like this:

```
/* the argument is a pointer to char* */
void fancyFunction(char** fancy)
{
    /* dereference the pointer (to char*) to assign */
    *fancy = realloc(*fancy, 200 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Lets suppose realloc() has to move all the garbage in my pointer 'fancy' to a new address. How could i return this new address …

In exactly the same way as `realloc` itself does it: by *returning* the new value:

```
char *fancyFunction(char *fancy) {
    return realloc(fancy, 200);
}
```

```
fancy = fancyFunction(fancy);
```

> … without using 'return'?

The alternative, as shown in the other answer, is to pass the value of `fancy` by pointer, and modifying the pointee. But for most cases, and by default (i.e. absent of specific reasons against it), using return values is preferred.

Comment: my function would be more handy and intuitive if you would use it in the mentioned way. And of course just for my curiosity.

Comment: @Yuki *my function would be more handy and intuitive if you would use it in the mentioned way*  No it's not.  Having to add another level of indirection makes it harder to use, harder to understand, and significantly more bug-prone.  Just ***return the value***.